# create a custom label with BorderColor property

Tags: vb.net, user-controls

I try to create a label with BorderColor property.but it not work . I create an instant object of this label in my form application and try to change the BorderColor , but nothing is happen.
this is my code :

```
Public Class MyLabel
Inherits Label

Private _BorderColor As Color
Dim e As New PaintEventArgs(Me.CreateGraphics, Me.DisplayRectangle)

Public Property BorderColor As Color
    Get
        Return _BorderColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        _BorderColor = value
        CreateBorder(value)
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub CreateBorder(ByVal value As Color)
    Dim g As Graphics = Me.CreateGraphics
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(value, 2)
    g.DrawRectangle(p, Me.DisplayRectangle)
End Sub

Private Sub MyLabel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    CreateBorder(_BorderColor)
End Sub
```

End Class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, no and double no.  You DO NOT call `CreateGraphics`.  A `Graphics` object is provided to you by the `Paint` event and you use that.  Also, you don't handle the `Paint` event in a custom control but rather override the `OnPaint` method.  Furthermore, if you have a method that does the drawing, e.g. `CreateBorder`, then you DO NOT call it from anywhere but the `OnPaint` method.  If you want to ensure that the border is repainted on the next event then you call `Invalidate`.  E.g.

```
Public Class BorderedLabel
    Inherits Label

    Private _borderColor As Color

    Property BorderColor As Color
        Get
            Return _borderColor
        End Get
        Set
            _borderColor = Value
            Invalidate()
        End Set
    End Property

    Protected Overrides Sub OnPaint(e As PaintEventArgs)
        MyBase.OnPaint(e)

        Using p As New Pen(BorderColor, 2)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(p, DisplayRectangle)
        End Using
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: ...you also do not change the PaintEventArgs

Comment: Use Invalidate(), never Refresh().

Comment: @HansPassant, I would say that in application code it is appropriate to call `Refresh` if you specifically want to ensure that a repaint occurs now. In control code though, you're probably correct that `Invalidate` is more appropriate.  I've made the change above.

Answer (score -1):

thanks ... now it work
this is the new code :

```
Public Class MyLabel
Inherits Label

Private _BorderColor As Color
Private _BorderSize As Single = 1.0F

Public Property BorderColor As Color
    Get
        Return _BorderColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        _BorderColor = value
        Refresh()
    End Set
End Property

Public Property BorderSize As Single
    Get
        Return _BorderSize
    End Get
    Set(value As Single)
        _BorderSize = value
    End Set
End Property

Private Sub CreateBorder(ByVal value As Color, ByVal e As PaintEventArgs)
    Dim g As Graphics = e.Graphics
    Dim p As Pen = New Pen(value, _BorderSize)
    g.DrawRectangle(p, Me.DisplayRectangle)
End Sub

Private Sub MyLabel_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    CreateBorder(_BorderColor, e)
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: There is very little difference between this and Mr  jmcilhinney's answer.  You should be gracious for the help and click the checkmark next to that answer.

Comment: Sure , you're right , but i can't find a checkmark for help , please show me ....thanka again